# Getting processes list in android 10

Tags: android, native, proc, ps

When i try to iterate through `/proc` directory in my native code by using standard library, the only process directory i can get is the directory related to my application process. On the other hand, `ps -e` is still able to get all the processes and as i've heard this utility is based on reading `/proc` contnts. So the question is how is that possible that `ps` can do it while my application is not allowed to. What are the ways of solving the problem? Thank you.

Comment: "the only process directory i can get is the directory related to my application process" -- access to `/proc` has been locked down for a couple of years. "ps -e is still able to get all the processes" -- not necessarily. It depends on the rights of the account that is running the command. An Android SDK application's account does not have many rights to access `/proc`, while other accounts (e.g., `adb shell`) may.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it only works with adb shell. But the device isn't rooted which means user needs no root access to get the processes. So what is it then? Security contexts?

Comment: AFAIK, the user account that `adb` uses has elevated privileges relative to what an Android SDK app process can hold.